# Take user input to call dataset into R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rvest

I have done some web scraping using rvest. I have code in an interactive r session that requires user input to call in different data (based on user interest) from the web source. Is it possible to prompt a user in Shiny in a similar fashion?

Comment: Sure - you could e.g. create a "wizard" via e.g. [shinyglide](https://juba.github.io/shinyglide/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can implement in R Shiny

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("dataset", "Upload a dataset in .csv format:"),
      selectInput("column", "Select a column:", choices = NULL)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$dataset)
    read.csv(input$dataset$datapath)
  })

  observe({
    choices <- colnames(data())
    updateSelectInput(session, "column", choices = choices)
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    req(input$column)
    data()[, input$column, drop = FALSE]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```